# Как сделать чтобы метод полностью выполнился перед переходом на другой?

Tags: java, циклы, консоль

У меня есть код (Я его изменил для наглядности) :

```
final String[] arr = {
        "Blue", "Magenta", "Orange", "Black"
};

for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    myPrint(i, arr[i]);
}

public static void myPrint(int line, String string) {
        System.out.print("int:");
        System.err.print(line);
        System.out.print("str1:");
        System.err.print(new String(string.toLowerCase().toUpperCase().toLowerCase().getBytes()));
        System.out.print("str2:");
        System.err.println(new String(string.toLowerCase().toUpperCase().toLowerCase().getBytes()));
}
```

Выводит (*не последовательно*):

```
Console:
        int:0str1:str2:int:str1:str2:blueblue
        1magentamagenta
        2orangeorange... и т.д (каждый раз немного по другому)
```

Должно получиться (*последовательно*):

```
Console:
        int:0str1:bluestr2:blueint:1str1:magenta... и т.д
```

**Как его дополнить, чтобы получилось как надо?**

Comment: Вы выводите в разные потоки: System.out и System.err. Используйте какой-то один поток.

Comment: Надо перенаправить поток.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Методом проб и ошибок нашел подходящее мне решение с использованием `Thread.sleep();` :

```
    final String[] arr = {
        "Blue", "Magenta", "Orange", "Black"
    };

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        myPrint(i, arr[i]);
    }

    public static void myPrint(int line, String string) {
        printout("int:");
        printerr(line);
        printout("str1:"
        printerr(new String(string.toLowerCase().toUpperCase().toLowerCase().getBytes()));
        printout("str2:");
        printerr(new String(string.toLowerCase().toUpperCase().toLowerCase().getBytes()));
    }
    private static long outtb = 0;
    private static long outta = 0;
    private static void printout() {
        outtb = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.print(o);
        System.out.flush();
        outta = System.nanoTime();
        try{Thread.sleep(0l,(int)((outta-outtb)*0.1f));}catch(Exception e){}
    }
    private static long errtb = 0;
    private static long errta = 0;
    private static void printerr() {
        long tb = System.nanoTime();
        System.err.print(o);
        System.err.flush();
        long ta = System.nanoTime();
        try{Thread.sleep(0l,(int)((errta-errtb)*0.1f));}catch(Exception e){}
    }
```

Все работает исправно, но код закономерно выполняется гораздо медленнее

100 итераций - 916 миллисекунд **с** `Thread.sleep();`

100 итераций - 16 миллисекунд **без** `Thread.sleep();`

Answer (score 2):

Вы используете разные потоки для вывода информации.
`System.out` - стандартный поток для вывода текста.
`System.err` - стандартный поток для вывода ошибок.

Соответственно в терминал они выводятся асинхронно.
Просто замените `err` на `out`

Comment: Понятно, а можно ли не заменять err на out, а как нибудь их синхронизировать?

Comment: @Jiftoo Попробуйте System.setErr(System.out) или полностью переопределите out и err на какую-то свою реализацию PrintStream в которой будут примитивы синхронизации.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, но попробуйте переназначить вывод для err. Хотя тогда проще заменить в вашем коде err на out